# Can I avoid debugger to stop in assembly code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, lldb, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging some Rust code and it pass throw places like:

[image]

I think this is some assembly code from rust libraries.
Is there any way to avoid to stop here? And just go throw readable code?
I already unflagged the option

```
Disassembly View: Show Source Code
Show Source Code in Disassembly View.
```

My `launch.json` is a very default one:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "launch",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=myproject",
                    "--package=myproject"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "myproject",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There aren't debug symbols and/or the code is optimized. Most probably `std`'s code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the extension CodeLLDB, you can disable this code break by going into File -> Preferences -> Settings (Ctrl+Comma) and under Extensions -> CodeLLDB select the option "never" under **Lldb: Show Disassembly**.

For me, this stopped the debug session from going into the assembly code. For example, if my assert!() had an error the session would exit rather than stopping in the assembly code first and then exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I note that the picture you posted shows Local Variables for `self` and `cx` in the Locals window.  If that Locals window is for the current frame - the one showing assembly instead of source - then you must have debug info for that frame (*).

If that's all true, it's much more likely be that you just don't have a local copy of the source files for this function.  Maybe you downloaded a debug version of the rust standard libraries and that's why it has debug info?  You can tell for sure by running the command:

```
(lldb) image lookup -va $pc
```

when stopped here.  If there are entries for CompileUnit and Function, etc. then you do indeed have debug info for this frame.

All of lldb's tests for "don't stop in code with no debug info" are about the presence of debug info, not whether we can find the associated sources.  So if you have debug info for a function, and your program gets into that function in the course of stepping, lldb will stop there.

You can modify this behavior on a library by library basis by adding the library name to the lldb setting `target.process.thread.step-avoid-libraries`.  It's a colon separated list of library names or paths.  If a `step` (but not `step-instruction`) operation ends up in a library on that list, lldb will step back out again regardless of whether it has debug info or not - which is I presume the behavior you want.

Alternately, if you want to step into this function provided you can see the sources, you can surely download the sources for the rust libraries that match the ones you have installed.  You  will likely also have to use the `target.source-map` setting to tell lldb where the sources are on your local system.

(*) Note, local variables can show up in non-debug functions if you have a "frame recognizer" registered for that function. lldb has no built-in recognizers for Rust, so you would have had to add that by hand which makes this possibility unlikely.  It doesn't sound like you were doing special things for this function.

Comment: You can also modify the "when to stop" behavior on a function by function basis - if that's necessary - by adding to the `target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp` setting.  If stepping stops in a function whose name matches that regex, then lldb will not stop in the function.

Comment: where exactly does this setting go? The question is about vscode but this doesn't help with actually enabling that setting in vscode

Comment: `"initCommands": ["settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-libraries std"]` in your launch config seems to work.. (might need to add more crates like `std:serde:regex:pathdiff`

Once this is enabled the frames show up as 'no source' in vscode and you can filter yours by using ctrl-f and searching for '.rs' and using the filter button

Comment: I don't know whether lldb-vscode reads your .lldbinit file or not, but that would be the conventional way to do this.